# Binary to decimal conversion in C#

Tags: c#, .net

This is how to convert from decimal to binary:

```
int dec = 42;
string bin = Convert.ToString(dec, 2);
```

How to convert  binary to decimal if I have

```
string bin = "0100101"
int dec = ???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just look for the reverse call - `Convert.ToInt32(value, fromBase)`:

```
int dec = Convert.ToInt32(bin, 2);
```